# How to bypass <li> clear tag

Tags: html, vba, ms-access

I am using below mentioned code for data extraction,but due to li clear tag unable to copy complete data using access vba.Guidence required regarding bypassing clear tag.My code is given below.

```
Set my_data = html4.getElementsByClassName("right_box")
For Each Item In my_data
Set my_data1 = Item.getElementsByTagName("li")
For Each item1 In my_data1
If item1.innerHTML Like "*href*" Then
href11 = item1.getElementsByTagName("a")
Else
Exit For
End If
```

And HTML data code is given below.

```
<div class="right_box">    <div class="right_box_title">        <div class="title_left"></div>        <a class="title_right" href="products.php?disp=1"></a>    </div>    <ul class="pro_list">   
<li>    <a title="NEW Handbags Handbags7" href="/index.php/NEW-Handbags-Handbags72-p20253745.html" class="pic"><img title="NEW Handbags Handbags7" alt="NEW Handbags Handbags7"   src="/image.php?pic=2017-08-27%2F2017082722393889955047.jpg&style=1&folder=uploadImage%2F" border="0" /></a>
    </li>
    <li class="clear"></li>
<li>
<a title="NEW Handbags Handbags6" href="/index.php/NEW-Handbags-Handbags6-p2025361.html" class="pic"><img title="NEW Handbags Handbags6" alt="NEW Handbags Handbags6"   src="/image.php?pic=2017-08-27%2F201708272239272285106.jpg&style=1&folder=uploadImage%2F" border="0" /></a>
    </li>
```

Above code stopped data at clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSS class should not prevent you from gathering data.

Note: You should set a reference to the **Microsoft HTML Object Library**.

This line of ↓ Code ↓ should fail due to `item1.getElementsByTagName("a")` returning an object and not a scalar value.

> href11 = item1.getElementsByTagName("a")

Here is a better pattern for iterating over anchor tags:

```
Dim a As HTMLAnchorElement 
Set my_data = html4.getElementsByClassName("right_box")(0)
For Each a In my_data.getElementsByTagName("a")
    Debug.Print a.href
Next
```

Comment: your above code displays error "Run time error 434 object does not support this property or method at following line "For Each a In my_data.getElementsByTagName("a")"

Comment: I updated my answer.  Because `.getElementsByTagName` returns a collection I needed to refer to an item in that collection `.getElementsByTagName (0)`.  The same mistake you made with `href11 = item1.getElementsByTagName("a")`

Comment: bundle of thanks for your response.Similarly when i use trailing code than it is copying data again and again i.e same data

Comment: Set my_data2 = html.getElementsByClassName("pad_t2")(0)
a1 = my_data2.innerText
Set my_data3 = a.getElementsByClassName("pad_t2")(1)
a2 = my_data3.innerText

Comment: html is following <li class="pad_t2"><div class="fl left"><strong>Color:</strong>&nbsp;Black &nbsp;

Comment: The a tags seemed to be paired.  One of the tsgs has a class the other does not.  You can test fot that to see which one you want

Comment: I want data from these two.so how i extract only one value.<li class="pad_t2"><div class="fl left"><strong>Color:</strong>&nbsp;Black &nbsp;<a href="http://www.51vogueking.cn/replica-christian-dior-white-new-style-upper-patent-leather-casual-shoes_p58182.html">White</a> &nbsp;</div><strong>Size:</strong>&nbsp;Middle &nbsp;</li>
            <li class="pad_t2"><div class="fl left"><strong>Brand:</strong>&nbsp; Christian Dior</div><strong>Item#:</strong>&nbsp;CDS6027-07</li>

Comment: `If a.className ="title_right"` or you can simply use a Collection or Dictionary to test for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

remove this li with clear class and manage the design using css appied in other li.

Comment: I replace li with clear class with blank value but still facing same error.using following methoed Set html = Ie.Document
      html4 = Replace(html, "clear", "")

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could use `querySelectorAll` and pass appropriate selector like this one `div[class='right_box'] ul[class='pro_list'] li a` which select all `a` inside `li` inside `ul with class pro_list` inside `div with class right_box`.  For more information about selectors see e.g. [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). HTH

```
Set html4 = ie.document

Dim selector As String
selector = "div[class='right_box'] ul[class='pro_list'] li a"

Dim anchors As IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
Set anchors = html4.querySelectorAll(selector)

Dim anchor, i
If Not anchors Is Nothing Then
    For i = 0 To anchors.Length - 1
        Set anchor = anchors.Item(i)
        Debug.Print "anchor-" & i & " href: " & anchor.href
    Next i
End If
```

*Output:*

```
anchor-0 href: file:///C:/index.php/NEW-Handbags-Handbags72-p20253745.html
anchor-1 href: file:///C:/index.php/NEW-Handbags-Handbags6-p2025361.html
```